# Usando draggable erro ao calcular a porcentagem

Tags: jquery, ui-draggable

Estou usando draggable do Jquery UI para fazer um efeito de arrastar (drag), a dificuldade está em calcular, de 0 a 100, a posição do drag dentro da barra. Veja o que já fiz:

```js
$('.drag').draggable({
 axis: 'x',
 containment: 'parent',
 drag: function() {
  var largura = $('.barra').width();
  var posicaoX = $(this).position().left;
  posicaoX = (posicaoX*100)/largura;
  var l = (100 * parseFloat($(this).position().left / parseFloat($(this).parent().width())));
  $('#mostra').val(l);
 }
});
```

```css
.barra{
  width: 150px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.drag{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #d18f4f;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="barra">
  <div class="drag"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" value="0" id="mostra">
```

O código aparentemente está certo, acredito que eu tenha que calcular o tamanho do drag e somar ou diminuir do total, ou algo assim, conseguem me ajudar?

Comment: Não vai chegar a 100 nunca porque está se baseando na borda esquerda do quadrado, e essa borda nunca irá tocar o final da barra.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o @Sam disse você tem que descontar a largura do botão, montei um exemplo com a correção.

```js
    $('.drag').draggable({
  axis: 'x',
  containment: 'parent',
  drag: function() {
   var largura = ($('.barra').width()) - 20;
   var posicaoX = $(this).position().left;
   var valor = (posicaoX * 100) / largura;
   $('#mostra').val(valor);
  }
 });
```

```css
 .barra{
  width: 150px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 .drag{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #d18f4f;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="barra">
 <div class="drag"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" value="0" id="mostra">
```